# How can I make a #gsub call work with encodings in both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I have the following code which requires Ruby 1.9, and I need to achieve the same functionality in Ruby 1.8. How can I accomplish this?

```
  # encoding: UTF-8
  ... [code omitted]
  body.force_encoding("UTF-8")
  body = body.gsub(/^(?=>)/, ">").gsub(/^(?!>)/, "> ")
```

`body` is a string obtained from an external source.

I think what I need is called a "shim" but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James Gray wrote a [series of articles](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) about dealing with encodings in Ruby. They're very good reading.

For 1.8.7 the [`jcode`](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/jcode/rdoc/index.html) library can help.

```
$KCODE = "U"
require 'jcode'
```